# How do you get a count (the number of) of all responses with certain attributes dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count, numbers

Right now my code looks like this:

```
Data <- Other_Data %>%
  dplyr::filter(Description == "Information" & Category == 1 & Cost >= 1000)
```

It creates a new table, which DOES give me the count of observations, which does answer the question that I am answering. But, I was wondering if there is a way to simply print the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `sum`

```
with(Other_Data, sum(Description == "Information" & 
           Category == 1 & Cost >= 1000, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the required data in `Data`. To get it's count you can do `nrow(Data)` which will count the number of rows in the `Data` and return the count that satisfies the condition in `filter`.